# VBA: Open file from cell then move to next cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I currently have a list of files with  the file path (C:/something.xlxs) in column B of a sheet. I want to write a Macro to read the value from the cell, open the file, and then move on to the next cell and open that file, etc.

I currently have this:

```
Sub openFiles()
    Dim sFullName As String
    Dim i      As Integer

    For i = 1 To 5
        If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2)) Then
            sFullName = Cells(i, 2).Value
            Workbooks.Open fileName:=Cells(i, 2).Value, UpdateLinks:=0

        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

It is only opening the first file from the list and then stopping. It is probably a small error but I am having trouble spotting it.

Thanks

Comment: You are using Cells() which is a method of ActiveSheet if you don't specify.  But when you open the workbook the active sheet changes.  You really need to specify the worksheet object yopu want Cells() to use.  You could save ActiveSheet to a variable at the start of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
Sub openFiles()
Dim sFullName As String
Dim i      As Integer
Dim wsh As Worksheet

On Error GoTo Err_openFiles

Set wsh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
i = 1
Do While wsh.Range("B" & i)<>""
    sFullName = wsh.Range("B" & i)
    Application.Workbooks.Open sFullName, UpdateLinks:=False
    i = i+1
Loop


Exit_openFiles:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wsh = Nothing
    Exit Sub

Err_openFiles:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, Err.Number
    Resume Exit_openFiles

End Sub
```

Above code works in context and provides a way to handle errors.

Comment: I tried that code and nothing happens when I go and run it

Comment: What is the name of sheet where the list of files is provided? Are there  empty cells?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sFullName)
```